# Make image fit div and resize accordingly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a forum in school, and I'm working on a profile page. On this profile page, I want to have a couple of banners that the users can choose from. I want to make these banners the same size as the div they're in. I also want them to be centred inside the div and resize it. Is it possible to do what I have shown in the two images where the banner get's cut off when it's resized?

This is my code:

```css
.user-pic {
    width: 120px;
    border: 3px solid #1b1b1b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
.user-pic:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.user-pic-overlay {
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #1b1b1b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 3;
}
.user-pic-overlay:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.user-header-wrap {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.user-header {
    height: 33vh;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #1b1b1b;
    box-shadow: 0 -25px 100px -22px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 2;
}
.user-header-pic {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
}
.user-header-pic-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 33vh;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.user-header-pic-overlay:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}
.user-header-nav {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 5px solid #1e1e1e;
    text-align: right;
    margin: auto;
}
.user-header-btn {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: .4em .6em;
    background-color: #424242;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}
.user-haeder-btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="user-header-wrap">
        <div class="user-header">
            <img class="user-header-pic" src="../images/header.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="user-pic" src="<?php echo $ppp;?>" alt="">
            <p class="prof-txt"><?php $ss = $_SESSION["GLOBALNAVN"]; echo $ss; ?></p>
            <p class="prof-txt-2">Level</p>
        </div>
        <div class="user-header-nav">
            <button class="user-header-btn">Edit Profile</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNF2O.jpg) [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Qjy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

added

```
.user-header-pic {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.user-pic {
    width: 120px;
    border: 3px solid #1b1b1b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
.user-pic:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.user-pic-overlay {
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #1b1b1b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    margin: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 3;
}
.user-pic-overlay:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.user-header-wrap {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 25px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.user-header {
    height: 33vh;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #1b1b1b;
    box-shadow: 0 -25px 100px -22px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 2;
}
.user-header-pic {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.user-header-pic-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 33vh;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
.user-header-pic-overlay:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}
.user-header-nav {
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 5px solid #1e1e1e;
    text-align: right;
    margin: auto;
}
.user-header-btn {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: .4em .6em;
    background-color: #424242;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}
.user-haeder-btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-header-wrap">
        <div class="user-header">
            <img class="user-header-pic" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553052944-763b0cbd086a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="">
            <img class="user-pic" src="<?php echo $ppp;?>" alt="">
            <p class="prof-txt"><?php $ss = $_SESSION["GLOBALNAVN"]; echo $ss; ?></p>
            <p class="prof-txt-2">Level</p>
        </div>
        <div class="user-header-nav">
            <button class="user-header-btn">Edit Profile</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So my that's not exactly what i want, i want to be able to keep the size of the image when the page is resized. Just like i showed in the two images i linked at the bottom of my post.

Comment: sorry forgot to add the image. check now